# How to say "okay" in French ?

Tags: anglais

Is **d'accord** the right word to say okay in French or are there any other words that can be used to say okay in French?

In what situation can I use **d'accord**?

I need an example of **d'accord**.

Comment: Consulting a dictionary could be a great help before you ask a question on FL. [This is quite a good online dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/OK), it will give you the various ways to say OK in French and lots of examples. If you are not sure what to use in a precise situation you have in mind then you can ask a more precise question here.

Comment: *OK* exists in french as well (don't write it *okay*).

Comment: “I need an example” “Vous avez besoin d'un exemple? D'accord!”

Comment: "Qu'il en soit ainsi".

Comment: One of the copains in *Le petit Nicolas* : "D'ac." Maîtresse : "Il faut que tu parles plus soigneusement." Copain : "D'ac, mademoiselle."

Comment: @LukeSawczak On the same line we can add "dacodac" . I don't hear it much nowadays, probably outmoded.

Comment: In English okay/OK is often used to introduce a new topic, not in the sense "I agree". For example, "OK, what can I do to help?" It is my understanding that "d'accord" can't be used in this way, but rather "bon" or "bien" should be used:  "Bon, en quoi puis-je être utile ?"

Comment: "In English okay/OK is often used to introduce a new topic, not in the sense "I agree". For example, "OK, what can I do to help?"

In my experience that is common in American English only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In spoken French you can say :

1. OK !
2. D'accord !
3. Je suis d'accord [avec toi].
4. OK, je suis d'accord [avec toi].

But you have to write :

1. Je suis d'accord [avec toi].

Source: I am French.

Answer (score 2):

You can say OK in French.

'Je suis d'accord' means 'I agree'

Comment: You can say it but it does not answer the question. D'accord is the translation of OK or Okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can say d'accord, but at least half of current usage would be 'OK'.  Throw in 'okey dokey' and you'll lose your audience completely though :-)

Comment: I see a fair amount "Okidok" (with a pronunciation close to 'okey dokey') in SMS and other informal short messages from my friends, and I hear from time to time, so I don't think your audience would be lost by "okey dokey". That said, most of my friends spend a lot of time listening/reading/watching stuff in English, so YMMV :)