# Is it correct to use "d'accord" to acknowledge request?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, conventions

I know that (a standalone) *d'accord* literally means *I agree*, but at the same time it is used more broadly to mean *OK* (in English).

My question is, does *d'accord* work as a response to a request?

For example, if someone asks me to do some shopping, can I say *D'accord* to mean *I will do the shpping*? My impression is that I can, but I suppose, in English, *I agree* is not possible in that context. So even if it *is* possible, is it a sort of accepted error?

---

Related questions:

- [How to say "okay" in French ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25557/how-to-say-okay-in-french)
- [Usage of d’accord?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/usage-of-d-accord)
- [How would I say "okay" or "fine"? (specific context)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/35925/how-would-i-say-okay-or-fine-specific-context)

Comment: *d'accord*  is just short for *je suis d'accord* and it seems that the [accepted answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29545/358) to the [question you link to](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29544/358) answers your question : **"*je suis d'accord* implies *je suis d'accord avec quelqu'un ou avec une suggestion, une idée, etc.* Meaning "I agree with someone/some idea..."**.  "– I will do the shopping  – OK (Right-o)"  *– Je vais faire les courses  – D'accord (D'accord/Ça marche/c'est bon)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of d’accord?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/usage-of-d-accord)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a widespread use of "d'accord".

"D'accord" expresses agreement: if you agree to someone asking you to do something it is implied that you are going to do it.

That said, it works as long as what you are asked is a direct request, but can feel uncanny as an answer to an implied request where there is no specified course of action:

This looks fine:

```
- Range tes affaires: on part dans cinq minutes et cette fois pas question d'être en retard!
- D'accord Maman...

- Tu peux faire la fermeture du magasin ce soir? Jean-Paul est malade et j'ai un diner de famille à préparer.
- D'accord, mais la semaine prochaine c'est toi qui prend le créneau du lundi matin.
```

This feels weird:

```
- On a besoin de plus de riz, qui va faire les courses ?
- D'accord
```

Sure, that person agrees they need more rice, but do they volunteer for shopping? It's unclear.